# Can I pair my Apple Watch 3 + cellular with iPhone 5s

Tags: iphone, apple-watch

I bought apple watch 3, but I didn't expect that it doesn't work with the iPhone 5s. Is there any way to disable the cellular functionality given that the GPS-only version should work with 5s?

Comment: Are you asking if you can pair your LTE Apple Watch with your iPhone 5s or how you can use your Watch without the LTE functionality?

Comment: @Jake3231I'm asking if there a way to pair 5s with LTE apple watch.